# Determining whether to INSERT or UPDATE in MySQL; query first or rely on constraint error?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-update

Assuming you have a scenario where there is a `PK`, but not an `auto-incremented PK` (so you would know if you have an existing record or creating a new one), what is the preferred best-practice way to code a check to do an `insert` vs. `update`.

1. Query for an existing PK first.
2. Do the update and if you get a constraint error, do an insert.
3. Some other way?

Answer (score 4):

The preferred way is `insert . . . on duplicate key update`.  This is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

The basic syntax is:

```
insert into t(col1, . . . coln)
    select val1, . . . valn  <---- could be constants
    from whatever
    on duplicate key set col1 = values(col1), col2 = values(col2), . . .;
```

Comment: This is a good alternative to Oracle's MERGE. But for the life of me, I can't understand why the syntax requires a column spec. It's (I would think) often superfluous. It should allow ... on duplicate key UPDATE;

Comment: @PeterNosko .. . Interesting point.  Perhaps MySQL just wants to be as verbose as the `MERGE` statement.  My preference would be for a keyword, something like `on duplicate key update nonkey columns`.